# Path diagram using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make a path diagram like this

[image]

using Tikz?

(Still a noob to Tikz)

Comment: "Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs" in the TikZ [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) might be of interest.  It explains in detail how to make these kinds of flow diagrams.

Comment: First create nodes (place them using positioning package right=of, left=of, above=of, etc), then assign name for each node, after that, connect them via `\draw`. Then you are done.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Next time, please show us what you have so far, even if that is only a beginning. It makes it much easier to help and avoids people having to start setting up things from scratch.

## *This answer contains 2 different solutions. The second (under EDIT below) is a modified version of the first which more closely matches the image in the question.*

Here's a fairly straightforward method, I think, which just uses the `positioning` library to place most of the nodes. 3 of the circles are placed using `calc` which is a little more involved, but `positioning` could be used here instead. The only other libraries used are one for the split node, `shapes.multipart`, and `arrows.meta` for a fancier arrow tip.

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,calc,arrows.meta}
```

The code uses a few styles, to avoid repeating things, and two loops, again to avoid repetition. The styles are defined at the start of the `tikzpicture` environment. You could use `\tikzset{}` outside that environment if you wanted to use the same styles for more than one picture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    basic/.style={draw, text centered},
```

The purpose of `basic` is to hold formatting options for all nodes.

```
    circ/.style={basic, circle, minimum size=2em, inner sep=1.5pt},
```

`circ` is for the circles. Note that it uses `basic` and then extends it by sepcifying the shape and size.

```
    rect/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, text height=1em, text depth=.5em},
```

`rect` similar to the `circ` style, but for rectangles.

```
    1 up 1 down/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal=false, rectangle split parts=2},
```

`1 up 1 down` is for the split node. See `shapes.multipart` in the manual for details. I'm not sure whether this is the best way to draw this or not. You might try alternatives to see if they work better.

```
    >={Stealth[]}
```

This just sets the default arrow tip style so that when we say `->`, we'll get a fancier tip than the default.

```
  ]
```

End of style definitions and start of picture code proper:

```
  \node [1 up 1 down] (base) {\strut$Y_d$\nodepart{two}\strut$C$};
```

This node is called `base` just because. It will be placed at the origin by default. We'll then place other nodes relative to this one. See `shapes.multipart` in the manual for the syntax used here within the node.

[image: base]

The next 4 nodes drawn are placed relative to `base` or relative to another node placed relative to `base`. The placement here relies on the `positioning` library. We draw the standard rectangles with `rect`:

```
  \node [rect, right=of base] (Ys) {$Y_s$};
  \node [rect, right=of Ys] (L) {$L$};
```

and the top and bottom leftmost circles, called `I` and `T`, with `circ`:

```
  \node [circ, above left=of base] (I) {$I$};
  \node [circ, below left=of base] (T) {$T$};
```

[image: next 4]

We then use a loop to place the remaining 3 nodes on the left relative to `I` and `T`. The `calc` library is used to position these relative to the topmost and bottommost nodes:

```
  \foreach \i [count=\ino] in {G,a,b}
```

Start the loop using variable `\i`. Keep count of the iteration using `\ino`.

```
    {
      \node [circ] at ($(I)!\ino/4!(T)$) (\i) {$\i$};
```

Place the relevant node in between `I` and `T`. The first node is placed 1/4 of the distance between them, the next at the halfway point, and the last at the 3/4 point.

[image: 5 circles]

```
      \draw [->] (\i) -- (base);
```

Draw the arrows to `base` for each of these 3 nodes.

[image: join 3]

Now close the loop:

```
    }
```

The last 2 nodes are placed relative to the rightmost node, `L` in the same way as `I` and `T` were placed relative to `base`:

```
  \node [circ, below=of L.south west] (K) {$K$};
  \node [circ, below=of L.south east] (c) {$c$};
```

[image: last 2]

Now we use a second loop to draw the remaining arrows. We use 2 variables: `\i` is the node to start the arrow from and `\j` is the arrow to draw the arrow to:

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {I/base,T/base,base/Ys,Ys/L,K/L,c/L} \draw [->] (\i) -- (\j);
```

[image: remaining arrows]

Finally, we fake the dashed line in the split `base` node by drawing a dashed line over the existing black line in white:

```
  \draw [white, densely dashed, shorten >=.4pt, shorten <=.4pt] (base.west) -- (base.east);
```

We are done:

```
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: flow diagram]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    basic/.style={draw, text centered},
    circ/.style={basic, circle, minimum size=2em, inner sep=1.5pt},
    rect/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, text height=1em, text depth=.5em},
    1 up 1 down/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal=false, rectangle split parts=2},
    >={Stealth[]}
  ]
  \node [1 up 1 down] (base) {\strut$Y_d$\nodepart{two}\strut$C$};
  \node [rect, right=of base] (Ys) {$Y_s$};
  \node [rect, right=of Ys] (L) {$L$};
  \node [circ, above left=of base] (I) {$I$};
  \node [circ, below left=of base] (T) {$T$};
  \foreach \i [count=\ino] in {G,a,b}
    {
      \node [circ] at ($(I)!\ino/4!(T)$) (\i) {$\i$};
      \draw [->] (\i) -- (base);
    }
  \node [circ, below=of L.south west] (K) {$K$};
  \node [circ, below=of L.south east] (c) {$c$};
  \foreach \i/\j in {I/base,T/base,base/Ys,Ys/L,K/L,c/L} \draw [->] (\i) -- (\j);
  \draw [white, densely dashed, shorten >=.4pt, shorten <=.4pt] (base.west) -- (base.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If something closer to the image shown in the question is desired, then we could handle the arrows a little differently on the left. This time, we postpone drawing all the arrows until almost the end, where we drew the final arrows before.

At this point, with all the nodes drawn, we start drawing arrows by drawing a single arrow with an extra large triangular tip from `a` to `base`.

```
  \draw [-{Triangle[length=5pt,width=5pt]}] (a) -- (base);
```

[image: extra-large triangular arrow]

A coordinate is placed at the centre-left of the arrow tip::

```
  \coordinate (arr) at ([xshift=-5pt]base.west);
```

`xshift` displaces the coordinate relative to `base.west`, which is the `west` anchor of `base`. Because the value is negative, the displacement is to the left. The value of `-5pt` is chosen to compensate for the `length` of the arrow tip which was `5pt`.

[image: coordinate for placement]

[The annotations in red are not part of the diagram. They are just to show the location of the coordinate since coordinates are not the kinds of things which can be seen in the output!]

This coordinate allows us to draw lines (rather than arrows) from the other circles on the left to the arrow tip.

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {G/arr,b/arr,I/arr,T/arr} \draw (\i) -- (\j);
```

[image: lines to overgrown triangular arrow]

The remaining arrows are then drawn using the loop as before.

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {base/Ys,Ys/L,K/L,c/L} \draw [->] (\i) -- (\j);
```

The default tip is changed to a triangular shape when setting up the `tikzpicture` so that the tips of these arrows are smaller versions of the arrow from `a` to `base`.

```
  [
    >={Triangle[]}
  ]
```

[image: alternate diagram]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={draw, text centered},
  circ/.style={basic, circle, minimum size=2em, inner sep=1.5pt},
  rect/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, text height=1em, text depth=.5em},
  1 up 1 down/.style={basic, text width=1.5em, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal=false, rectangle split parts=2},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    >={Triangle[]}
  ]
  \node [1 up 1 down] (base) {\strut$Y_d$\nodepart{two}\strut$C$};
  \node [rect, right=of base] (Ys) {$Y_s$};
  \node [rect, right=of Ys] (L) {$L$};
  \node [circ, above left=of base] (I) {$I$};
  \node [circ, below left=of base] (T) {$T$};
  \foreach \i [count=\ino] in {G,a,b} \node [circ] at ($(I)!\ino/4!(T)$) (\i) {$\i$};
  \node [circ, below=of L.south west] (K) {$K$};
  \node [circ, below=of L.south east] (c) {$c$};
  \draw [-{Triangle[length=5pt,width=5pt]}] (a) -- (base);
  \coordinate (arr) at ([xshift=-5pt]base.west);
  \foreach \i/\j in {G/arr,b/arr,I/arr,T/arr} \draw (\i) -- (\j);
  \foreach \i/\j in {base/Ys,Ys/L,K/L,c/L} \draw [->] (\i) -- (\j);
  \draw [white, densely dashed, shorten >=.4pt, shorten <=.4pt] (base.west) -- (base.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer was actually quite informative.

Comment: `(base.west) -- (base.east);` when I think too much while the answer right there. :)

Comment: @CroCo Sorry. What do you mean?

Comment: @cfr, I mean you are clever and smart. your solution for the dashed line is efficient and simple. Sometimes the answer right there while you're heading in the wrong direction. I mean for my case. :)

Comment: One problem though regarding the arrow between Yd and Ys. It seems to me the arrow should be shifted up a bit so that the boxes Yd and Ys are connected while C box is not.

Comment: @CroCo Your solutions are smart, too. Just sometimes everyone doesn't see the obvious. Or maybe I've seen the trick before. (I don't remember, but that doesn't mean my unconscious doesn't.) Re. arrow: Why? Perhaps you know what the diagram means, but to me it is just a bunch of meaningless letters in boxes and circles. So I have no idea what would make sense and what not. In the original, there's a single arrow, but I'm not sure if that is what's really needed or just an approximation.

Comment: @cfr, I might be wrong though but this is what I see from the picture. I hope I'm not heading in the wrong direction this time. :)

Comment: @CroCo I've edited to add an alternative which matches the picture in the question a little more closely.

Answer (score 13):

This might give you a starting point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick,>={Triangle[]},
  circ/.style = {draw,circle,minimum size=5ex},
  rect/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=5ex},
  splt/.style = {draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,minimum size=3ex}
  ]
  \matrix[row sep=2ex,column sep=1em] {
    \node[circ] (I) {$I$}; \\
    \node[circ] (G) {$G$}; \\
    \node[circ] (a) {$a$}; &&
    \node[splt] (Yd) {$Y_d$ \nodepart{two} $C$}; &&
    \node[rect] (Ys) {$Y_s$}; &&
    \node[rect] (L) {$L$}; \\
    \node[circ] (b) {$b$}; &&&&&
    \node[circ] (K) {$K$}; &&
    \node[circ] (c) {$c$}; \\
    \node[circ] (T) {$T$}; \\
  };
  \foreach \n in {I, G, a, b, T}
    \draw[->] (\n) -- (Yd);
  \draw[->] (Yd) -- (Ys);
  \draw[->] (Ys) -- (L);
  \foreach \n in {K, c}
    \draw[->] (\n) -- (L);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]