# Controlling distance from the arrow with auto=left

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's a minimal graph drawn in tikz, placing edge nodes with `auto=left`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
    \node at (2,1) (B) {B}; 
    \node at (3,0) (C) {C}; 
    
    \path[->] (A) edge node[auto=left] {x} (B);
    \path[->] (B) edge node[auto=left] {y} (C);
    \path[->] (C) edge node[auto=left] {z} (A);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the edge nodes (x, y, z) are further away from the arrows than I would like. How can I adjust this distance?

To be clear: I don't want to manually fine-tune the location of each edge label. (e.g. I don't want to use "above", "below" etc. to place them in relation to the midpoint of the line, because that would have to be specified separately for each one.) Instead I want to use `auto=left` / `auto=right` or equivalent functionality, but just have it place the labels a bit closer to the edges. This is because my plots are generated automatically and I don't have the ability to manually adjust each one.

Comment: It feels like a hack, and it won't adjust correctly to the size of the label, but I'm able to adjust it with `\path[->] (A) edge node[auto=left, inner sep=0.5mm] {x} (B);`, which will do for now. I tried searching the manual for "auto=" and didn't find any information about fine tuning the placement, but of course it might be somewhere else in that huge pdf.

Comment: If you don't want fine tuning of the nodes' positions, why don't you have a look at the `graphs` library?

Comment: @FelixEmanuel I will fix my question. By "nodes" I meant the nodes that form the edge labels. (x, y and z in my figure, rather than A, B and C.) If I correctly understand what the graphs library is responsible for, it doesn't deal with the placement of those nodes at all.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the distance between the text (the label) and the arrow to be always the same, right?

Comment: @AndréC in an ideal world, yes. But I realise that's impossible, because TeX only knows the bounding box, not the actual shape of the letter. The solution `inner sep` solution in both the answers is actually fine - I will accept yours now

Comment: I think it's achievable, creating a new style, I'm thinking about it. We agree that the distance between the text and the arrow is the distance between a point and a line in the mathematical sense... [Distance from a point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With TikZ, a `node` is a box that contains text. This default box is **rectangular**. If it perfectly frames the text, the edges of the box touch the text, which is unattractive.

By default TikZ leaves a space between the text and the edges of the box which is defined by the length ìnner sep (initially is `0.3333em`).

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\tikzset{every node/.style={draw}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
    \node at (2,1) (B) {B}; 
    \node at (3,0) (C) {C}; 
    
    \path[->] (A) edge node[auto=left,draw,inner sep=3em] {x} (B);
    \path[->] (B) edge node[auto=left,draw] {y} (C);
    \path[->] (C) edge node[auto=left,draw,inner sep=0em] {z} (A);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
    \node at (2,1) (B) {B}; 
    \node at (3,0) (C) {C}; 
    
    \path[->] (A) edge node[blue,auto=left,draw,inner sep=3em,label={[blue,above]:$\text{inner sep}=3em$}](bigx) {x} (B);
    \node[inner sep=0pt](smallx) at (bigx){x};
    \draw[|<->,red] (smallx.west)--(bigx.west)node[midway,below,font=\footnotesize]{$3em$};
    \path[->] (B) edge node[red,auto=left,draw,label={[red,above right,align=center]:initially\\$\text{inner sep}=0.3333em$}] {y} (C);
    \path[->] (C) edge node[violet,auto=left,draw,inner sep=0em,label={[violet,below,yshift=-5pt]:$\text{inner sep}=0em$}] {z} (A);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the node is a circle, this circle is **circumscribed** to the rectangular node which is drawn by default.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[draw=red] (a) at (0,0){A};
\node[draw=blue,circle] (a) at (0,0){A};
\node[align=center,font=\tiny] at (0,-.8) {same node with \textcolor{blue}{circle}\\ and \textcolor{red}{rectangular} shape};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1  excellent  -this further increase my education

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to the labels above the edges/arrows

Each label has been defined as a node -- a node always has some reserved space around it defined by the key `inner sep`

The key can be set globally at the beginning including the auto key so as to move the label and all nodes close to the edges/ or further

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt,auto=left, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
....
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt,auto=left, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
    \node at (2,1) (B) {B}; 
    \node at (3,0) (C) {C}; 
    
    \path[->] (A) edge node {x} (B);
    \path[->] (B) edge node{y} (C);
    \path[->] (C) edge node {z} (A);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

An even better option is to define labels as labels rather than nodes  -- please see my answer here --

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558016/197451

The same code modified (without `inner sep` invocation)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
    \node at (2,1) (B) {B}; 
    \node at (3,0) (C) {C}; 
    
    \path[draw] (A) edge[->] node [pos=0.5, above,  sloped,](){x} (B);
    \path[draw] (B) edge[->] node [midway, label={[label distance=-13pt, 
    rotate=45]135:$y$}](){}(C);
    \path[draw] (C) edge[->] node [midway, label={[label distance=-6pt, 
    rotate=0]-90:z}](){} (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]